# Database.com Mobile Application Authorization Questions

Tags: android, ios, rest, salesforce, force.com

I'm working a mobile application for Android and iOS (native in both cases) that will be using Database.com behind the scenes as the database. I need this intergration to be tansparent to the user. The users of the app will not be logging into or authenticating with Database.com at all, it should simply be working behind the scenes a cloud database. I will simply be using an integration user hardcoded into the application.

I've been having an extremely difficult time of finding any of examples of how to build an app with the MobileSDK where I don't have to take advantage of the user-agent OAuth flow that displays a view to the app user. zkSforce has been mentioned as a possible solution for iOS (and it looks like it could be) but I haven't found even any basic tutorials on how to implement this with inconjunction with the mobile sdk to get access to the REST API (by bypassing the login view for the user). I also have yet to find anything at all for Android other than just taking advantage of the standard Java SDK or importing the web service wsdl and working from there through SOAP.

So is there anyone out there who can point me in the direct of some examples of behind the scenes authentication and use of the Mobile SDK REST methods or is my best option here to go to using the SOAP solutions behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm), which will allow you to use already known username and password with an OAuth-style flow. This is preferred to making a SOAP call in an app that is using the REST API everywhere else.